# in joomla component ajax response

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am trying to display the response of ajax call in my component. but every time response has whole template with header and footer. I need only content displayed by component. is there any solution for this? I have tried using 'tmpl=component'. but this is not working in joomla 2.5.

Comment: you could show the code that didnt work for you...

Answer (score 1):

add `&format=raw` to existing url

or
 `tmpl=raw` and try

it worked for me in 1.5... not sure about 2.5.. give it a try n let me know pls

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the joomla to attach the header/footer  and ... to your output ajax data, you must add this code after displaying your data

```
global $mainframe;
$mainframe->close();
```